# Emails sent from Java not received at Yahoo & Gmail

Tags: java, email, content-type, email-attachments, email-headers

I have a problem where a piece of code in java sends emails just fine except to public emails like Yahoo & Gmail.

Here are the headers for the email I receive when sent to my company email address:

```
Date: Wed, 30 Apr 2014 10:56:05 -0400
From: <test@mycompany.com>
To: <testmycompany@gmail.com>
Message-ID: <743410318.7.1398869765575.JavaMail.test@test-win7>
Subject: Order Attached
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="----=_Part_6_255846116.1398869765268"
Return-Path: test@mycompany.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: S1P5HUB7.EXCHPROD.USA.NET
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AVStamp-Mailbox: SMEXtG}w;1076300;0;This mail has
 been scanned by Trend Micro ScanMail for Microsoft Exchange;
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 0
X-EsetId: B021473D1D017139E26C16
```

Here's the java code:

```
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
      msg.setHeader("Content-Type", getContentType(email.getContentType()));
      msg.setFrom(getInternetAddress((email.getFrom() == null || email.getFrom().getEmail() == null) ? new EmailAddress(emailConfiguration.getDefaultFromEmail()) : email.getFrom()));
      msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, getRecipientArray(email.getRecipients()));
      msg.setSubject(email.getSubject(), getContentType(email.getContentType()));
      msg.setSentDate(new Date());
  if (email.getAttachments() == null || email.getAttachments().size() == 0) {
    msg.setContent(new String(email.getBody()), getContentType(email.getContentType()));
  } else {
    MimeMultipart body = new MimeMultipart();
    email.setBody("This is a new Vendor Order.\nPlease respond.");
    if (email.getBody() != null && email.getBody().length > 0) {
      MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
      textPart.setContent(new String(email.getBody()), getContentType(email.getContentType()));
      body.addBodyPart(textPart);
    }
    for (EmailAttachment attachment: email.getAttachments()) {
      MimeBodyPart part = new MimeBodyPart();
      InMemoryDataSource fds = new InMemoryDataSource(attachment);
      part.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
      part.setFileName(fds.getName());
      body.addBodyPart(part);
    }
    msg.setContent(body);
  }

  transport = mailSession.getTransport(msg.getFrom()[0]);
  Socket socket = new Socket(emailConfiguration.getMailHost(), emailConfiguration.getMailPort());
  socket.setSoTimeout(emailConfiguration.getIdleTimeoutInSeconds() * 1000);
  if (connectionListener != null) {
    connectionListener.setSocket(socket);
  }
  ((SMTPTransport)transport).connect(socket);
  transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
```

Is there anything that jumps out at you that maybe missing from the headers?

Answer (score 0):

You should check what the mail server responds. I tried to connect to gmail servers once to check the existence of a mail address, but it didn't work because the ip block of my ISP is blacklisted to avoid spam from infected home computers. I forgot the link, but there is a site where you can check whether your ip is blacklisted.